# Gray out disabled Controls in Access VBA after disabling the Control

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access form with many tabs and subforms.  I have written some VBA code for a button that disables/enables all of the controls on all of the subforms.  For some reason the buttons will not gray out like they do if you manually set their Enabled property to False.  Does anyone know how to achieve this with the VBA code?

Thank you!

Below is the code that I used:

```
Private Sub Command137_Click()
    Dim ctrlControl As Control
    For Each ctrlControl In Me.Controls
    On Error GoTo err:
    If ctrlControl.ControlType = acTabCtl Or ctrlControl.Name =     "Command9" Then

    Else
        ctrlControl.Enabled = False      
    End If
Continue:
Next
Exit Sub
err:
    Debug.Print err.Description
    Resume Continue
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you enabling/disabling it? I do this all the time and have never seen this issue.

Comment: I just added the VBA code that I am using in my original post.  Thanks!

Comment: See if all controls are in the loop: before `On Error GoTo err` put: `Debug.Print  ctrlControl.Name & vbCrLf` to see that all controls are actually iterated.

Comment: I debugged it, they all are iterated.  None of them fall into the error trapping.  The disabling of the buttons actually works, however the buttons don't gray out.  Is there another property that controls this?  I notice when I change a button control manually to disabled it grays out.

Comment: I don't know... this code should work for controls in one form, main form,referred to by `Me` key word. It shouldn't affect controls on sub forms. How does disabling buttons on sub-forms Work using this code?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem as well. However, I figured out a way to get around it.

first define some public variables in a module:

```
Option Explicit
Public greyout, white As Long
```

then in your Form_Load() sub

```
Public Sub Form_Load()
    'color RGB definition
    greyout = RGB(210, 210, 210)
    white = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub
```

then when you use .enable on your text/combo boxes, do this

```
me.textbox.enabled = false
me.textbox.backcolor = greyout

me.textbox.enabled = true
me.textbox.backcolor = white
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for the wrong controlType.   Use 'acCommandButton' not 'acTabCtrl'.   (I added an ELSE to enable everything else)

```
IF ctrlControl.ControlType = acCommandButton THEN
   ctrControl.enabled = false
ELSE
   ctrControl.enabled = true
END IF
```

Comment: Your original question was talking about "buttons", if you're looking to disable textboxes, then you need to search for acTextBox